# Web Hosting Checklist

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am a web developer that is starting to look into hosting his own website. I would like to showcase my programming skills (PHP, MySQl, C#, Wordpress).

My knowledge of languages I am OK with but the actually hosting site is where my knowledge starts to get a little shaky. I know the basics (bandwidth, sub-domains, re-write rules) but I would love your input, to help me formulate a check list of certain web-hosting services that I should be on the look-out for.

Also I was wondering if there were any reliable hosting providers who give you the option to host both c# code-behinds and PHP code. As I would like to have two versions of my site, one in C# and one in PHP the hope is that if I need to look for another job this website will help me show possible employers my server side knowledge.

I hope this is enough info, I did some researching online but found a bunch of unless articles and I've always have had luck on the StackExchange sites. So hopefully you, can help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most important issues for me is support.

What I used to do before becoming a host myself was email or phone a companies tech support with a question and see how long it took to be answered. IF the sales telephone gets picked up straight away but support rings off... walk away.

If they were too slow they got crossed off the list.

**Other things to look out for are**

- Do they offer a fully featured control panel ie CPanel.
- Subdomains
- private directories
- mailing lists
- can you easily have extra Perl or PHP modules added
- Do they offer one click software installs like Softalicious.
- Do they give you shell access for testing scripts
- what about backups, do they provide them, are their costs for restores.
- What is their SLA with regards to downtime.
- What are their downtime stats.
- What are their policies on overuse? Would they sting you or be fair about it
- Do they offer email spam protection
- Visitor logs/stats
- Is there a DNS editor?
- Custom 404 pages
- Databases... how many what type
- Do you have phpMyAdmin etc
- Does the hosting package you're interested in have enough RAM memory you'll need. Often times 500MB is not enough with everything running. What would it cost to increase the dedicated ram if needed?
- What things will they manage and what will you be responsible for (example will they upgrade the control panel for you if there's a security update or will you have to)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the kinda of checklist I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Most hosts try to blind you with huge figures for disk space, emails and bandwidth which in reality you more than likely don't actually require.

Answer (score 0):

- Verify if your site is optimized to conserve bandwidth usage (HTTP
  Compression is enabled, JS & CSS files are minified, etc)
- Try [Microsoft's search tool to compare Web Hosting providers](http://www.microsoft.com/web/Hosting/Home)

Here is a ["meta-list" on tips related to ASP.NET Hosting & Deployment](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2007/09/tips-on-aspnet-hosting-deployment.html)